# Custom module to act on module configuration change

Tags: 8, hooks, navigation

I'm working on a custom module to change the administrative menu structure. A few extra menu items are added; for some of them, I want to be able the change the name via a configuration page of the module.

This might sound like a lot of work for creating a few menu items, and it might be, but I hope it will save me some time in the future when setting up the site for my clients.

I think it is a good way to learn how to create custom modules with configuration pages (I only created modules without configuration pages) till now.

I have a custom module in the `modules/custom/svds_adminmenu` folder. Structure inside this folder is:

- src

  - Form

    - ModuleConfigurationPage.php
- svds_adminmenu.info.yml
- svds_adminmenu.module
- svds_adminmenu.routing.yml

This is what I have at this moment:

**ModuleConfigurationPage.php**

```
namespace Drupal\svds_adminmenu\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Defines a form that configures forms module settings.
 */
class ModuleConfigurationForm extends ConfigFormBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'svds_adminmenu_admin_settings';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
        return [
            'svds_adminmenu.settings',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $config = $this->config('svds_adminmenu.settings');
        $form['link_title'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Link Title'),
            '#default_value' => $config->get('link_title'),
        ];
        $form['link_path'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Link Path'),
            '#default_value' => $config->get('link_path'),
        ];
        return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $values = $form_state->getValues();
        $this->config('svds_adminmenu.settings')
            ->set('link_title', $values['link_title'])
            ->set('link_path', $values['link_path'])
            ->save();
        parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
    }
}
```

**svds_adminmenu.info.yml**

```
name: Change Admin Menu
description: 'Change Admin Menu'
type: module
package: SVDS
core: 8.x
configure: svds_adminmenu.admin_settings
```

**svds_adminmenu.module**
*I first created the module so it creates the menu items on install, now I want to change it to create/edit on configuration page save. So I don't want to use the hook_install anymore.*

```
use Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent;

function svds_adminmenu_install() /*don't want to use this hook anymore*/
{
    $menu_main = 'administration';

    $content_overview = MenuLinkContent::create([
        'title' => 'Content Overview',
        'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/admin/content'],
        'menu_name' => $menu_main,
        'expanded' => FALSE,
        'parent' => 'system.admin_content',
        'weight' => -10,
        'id' => 1000,
    ]);

    $content_overview->save();

    $content_edit = MenuLinkContent::create([
        'title' => 'Edit Content',
        'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/admin/content'],
        'menu_name' => $menu_main,
        'expanded' => TRUE,
        'parent' => 'system.admin_content',
        'weight' => 1,
        'id' => 1001,
    ]);

    $content_edit->save();

    $content_edit_sub = MenuLinkContent::create([
        'title' => /* CONFIG LINK TITLE HERE */,
        'link' => ['uri' => /* CONFIG LINK PATH HERE */],
        'menu_name' => $menu_main,
        'expanded' => TRUE,
        'parent' => 1002,
        'weight' => 0,
    ]);

    $content_edit_sub->save();
}


function svds_adminmenu_uninstall(){
    $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::load(1000);
    $menu_link->delete();
    $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::load(1001);
    $menu_link->delete();
    $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::load(1002);
    $menu_link->delete();
}
```

**svds_adminmenu.routing.yml**

```
svds_adminmenu.admin_settings:
  path: '/admin/config/svds/admin_menu'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\svds_adminmenu\Form\ModuleConfigurationForm'
    _title: 'SVDS Admin Menu Configuration'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

So I know how to programmatically create menu items, and I have a configuration page. Now I have to connect the two things together: When the configuration is changed, the module should run again to change the menu.

I found this to fetch the configuration data.

```
$variables['var'] = \Drupal::config('my_module.settings')->get('var');
```

I have to trigger my action via some kind of hook, and I don't know which one. It should only trigger once after the configuration is changed, not on a preprocess function, or something similar.

So how can I do this?

Comment: You don't need a hook, that code would usually go in your config form's submit method. Could you update the question with a bit more info about what you mean by "change the menu"? What do you need to happen precisely? Creating/editing a menu item is easy, but it's not clear if that's all you need to know, or what your config form should contain

Comment: I changed my question, added extra code to give a better idea of what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Clive said I don't need a hook and .module file to do this. This is what I did.

I copied the code from my .module file to the ModuleConfigurationPage.php and put it inside the submitForm function:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $menu_main = 'administration';
    //catch values from the form
    $linkTitle = ($form['settings']['main']['link_title']['#value']);
    $linkPath = ($form['settings']['main']['link_path']['#value']);

    //delete dynamically created menu items
    for($i = 1000; $i <= 1002; $i++){
        $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::load($i);
        if($menu_link) {
            $menu_link->delete();
        }
    }

    //create content overview link in content dropdown
    $content_overview = MenuLinkContent::create([
        'title' => 'Content Overview',
        'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/admin/content'],
        'menu_name' => $menu_main,
        'expanded' => FALSE,
        'parent' => 'system.admin_content',
        'weight' => -10,
        'id' => 1000,
    ]);

    $content_overview->save();

    //create content edit content link in content dropdown
    $content_edit = MenuLinkContent::create([
        'title' => 'Edit Content',
        'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/admin/content'],
        'menu_name' => $menu_main,
        'expanded' => TRUE,
        'parent' => 'system.admin_content',
        'weight' => 1,
        'id' => 1001,
    ]);

    $content_edit->save();

    //create menu item with config settings
    $content_edit_sub = MenuLinkContent::create([
        'title' => $linkTitle,
            'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:'.$linkPath],
            'menu_name' => $menu_main,
            'expanded' => TRUE,
            'parent' => 1002,
            'weight' => 0,
     ]);

    $content_edit_sub->save();

    //set new config values
    $this->config('svds_adminmenu.settings')
        ->set('link_title', $linkTitle)
        ->set('link_path', $linkPath)
        ->save();

    //refresh menu cache to see changes
    $renderCache = \Drupal::service('cache.menu');
    $renderCache->invalidateAll();

    //submit form
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
}
```

This way the menu gets updated each time you click the submit button.